# On Android, is there a Thread Safe method for storing Shared Preferences?

Tags: android, encryption

Key word here is threadsafe. The Jetpack Encrypted Shared Preference and file methods are not threadsafe. We want to store some public/private key in an encrypted storage so that it cannot easily be hacked.

Answer (score 3):

I don't why you exactly need thread-safe calls to store the keys in SharedPreferences but if concurrency is the concern, you can use Datastore. I am attaching a comparison to help you make the decision.

[image]

You can read more about it [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/09/prefer-storing-data-with-jetpack.html).